# Get base image name with extension in javascript

Tags: javascript

I got the following string from a Json:

image/folder/folder/xxx.jpg

I would like to explode the xxx.jpg and keep it to local var.

thanks

Comment: `string.split('/').pop();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can try with : `var newString = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('/')+1);`

Answer (score 0):

Split it using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string/split) method and get the last value from the array using [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method.

```js
var string = " image/folder/folder/xxx.jpg";

var res = string.split('/').pop();

console.log(res);
```